# Deciding whether or not one series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to determine whether or not the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n\cdot \sqrt{n}}$$

is convergent?

I couldnt do such problems. What is the way? How should I think?

I edited the parentheses.

Comment: Please check to make sure that I wrote what you intended. You should also read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) to learn about accepting answers and why you should.

Comment: I doubt you would be asked a question in which the $n^{1/2}$ so obviously cancel. Maybe parentheses went astray?

Comment: I changed $ln n$, coded as "ln n", to $\ln n$, coded as "\ln n".  That is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a clarification, which changes the answer. We are looking at 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n+(-1)^nn^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n\cdot n^{\frac{1}{2}}}.$$
This can be split as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

The second is an alternating series, which converges.

For the first, note that if $n$ is large enough, then $\log n \lt n^{1/4}$. It follows that if $n$ is large enough,
$$0\lt \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}}\lt \frac{n^{1/4}}{n^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}.$$
So the sum converges, by comparison with the "$p$-series" $\sum_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{5/4}}$.

Thus our original series converges.

Answer (score 7):

By expanding out the brackets you cans split it into two series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\ln n+(-1)^n\right)n^{1/2}}{n\cdot n^{1/2}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\ln n}{n}}+{\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}}$$
The second series is the alternating Harmonic, widely known to be convergent. This can be verified by the [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). The first series however, when you apply [Ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), you will find that:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\ln{(n+1)}}{\ln{n}}\frac{n}{n+1}$$
Which has a limit of $1$ as $n \to \infty$, so the ratio test in inconclusive. However, we can compare it term by term with the Harmonic series:
$$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\ln n}{n} \forall n > 1$$
Hence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\ln n}{n}} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And the right hand side is known to diverge ([Harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29)), hence the entire series must diverge.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n+(-1)^nn^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n\cdot n^{\frac{1}{2}}}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n }{  n^{\frac{3}{2}} } + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n }{n}\,. $$

Now, the first series on the RHS converges by the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) and the second series converges by the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). So the whole series converges.